# VBA to copy Pivot table and remove the Connection with data

Tags: vba, pivot

Wondering if there is any way to copy a Pivot table using VBA to another worksheet removing the link with datasource, in order to have a snapshot based on that date.

Cheers,

Gilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, here you go:

```
Sub ptValues()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim dest As Range

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1) 'set pivot table
    data = pt.TableRange1 'read data into variant array
    Set dest = Cells(1, 10) 'set destination range left upper corner

    dest.Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value2 = data 'write data to worksheet


End Sub
```